# Are dipole interactions considered short range in 2d

Tags: fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics, potential, dipole-moment

Every paper that I read about dipole-dipole interactions always call them long-range interactions. Is dipole-dipole interactions can be considered short-range in 2D? As we know it behaves as $\thicksim \frac{1}{r^3}$ and the integral of this over space in 2D does not diverge to $\infty$...

Comment: @DavidSaykin the integral doesn’t diverge! And I think OP is talking about physical dipoles confined to a 2D plane, which have $1/r^3$ interactions as claimed.

Comment: @JahanClaes Thank you for clearing this out, It is obvious that it does not diverge, it's just a 101 math. And yes, of course you can have dipoles with $1/r^3$ in 2D.